# how do I pass a user inputted integer through methods?

Tags: java, class, methods, int

Essentially i've isolated the issue, the int numpersons begins as 0. I take a user input to make it a particular number which is the array size, when the second method begins it takes the 0 again and then the array has an out of bounds exception. I want to pass it from one method to the next, or make them more successive, idk how to do this

thanks in advance

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BankApp {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int numpersons = 0;
private SavingsAccount[] clients = new SavingsAccount[numpersons];

public BankApp() {
    while (numpersons < 1) {
        System.out.println("How many people are there?");
        numpersons = input.nextInt();
        if (numpersons < 1 || 2147483647 < numpersons) {
            System.out.println("invalid number, please enter again");
        }
    }
    input.nextLine();
}

public void addClients() {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < numpersons) {
        System.out.println("enter account id " + (i + 1));
        String AccountID = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("enter account name " + (i + 1));
        String AccountName = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("enter account balance " + (i + 1));
        Double AccountBalance = input.nextDouble();
        clients[i] = new SavingsAccount(AccountID, AccountName, AccountBalance);
        input.nextLine();
        i++;
    }
}

public void displayClients() {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < numpersons) {
        System.out.println("======================================");
        System.out.println("Account ID " + (i + 1) + ": " + clients[i].getID());
        System.out.println("Account Name " + (i + 1) + ": " + clients[i].getName());
        System.out.println("Account Balance " + (i + 1) + ": " + clients[i].getBalance());
        System.out.println("======================================");
        i++;
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    BankApp ba = new BankApp();
    ba.addClients();
    ba.displayClients();

}
```

}

Comment: The problem isn't the integer, it's the array. You are creating it when `numpersons` is 0. You need to instantiate it when you have actually assigned a value to `numpersons`

Comment: NB: ``if (2147483647 < numpersons) {`` is always ``false``: you cant store an "int" value bigger than this constant (btw, use ``Integer.MAX_VALUE`` when refering to the maximum value of an integer.)

Comment: These two lines (`int numpersons = 0;
private SavingsAccount[] clients = new SavingsAccount[numpersons];`) are executed one right after the other, before the constructor is executed. So you're constructing an array of length 0. You need to construct the array inside the constructor, **after** you have read the length.

Comment: "The array must only be declared at the object member variable-level."
This is a part of the assignment requirements, im not 100% sure what this means, but if this does have to remain at the top then what do I do?

Comment: You're confusing **declaration**, which is the part `private SavingsAccount[] clients`, and **initialization**, which is the part `clients = new SavingsAccount[numpersons];`. You can (and must) declare a variable without initializing it, and only initialize it later

Comment: thankyou so much for this clarification. It's always the learning part thats most important isnt it, now I understand why it didnt work and how to complete the assignment to the liking of the assessors
appreciated